# button to navigate the pages of UIpageViewController from witin a VC. objective c, ios, xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i have a VC with a button inside it.
i would like to change the UIpageViewController page when it is clicked, the page view is all over the screen and contains the VC.
note: the action of the button is in the VC and the changing of the page should be in the VC as well NOT in the pageview.
any way to do that, thanks!.

Comment: Why the need for a button? Why not just use the swipe of screen?

Comment: for the user, so he could navigate more easily.

Comment: correction: so he could have another way to navigate

Comment: @Leon have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how have set out your project. If you have a fixed amount of pages you could have the same amount of buttons and simply change the index:

In your .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
```

In your .m, to change the page.

```
//This is a button action
- (IBAction)page1:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    //pageViewController is declared in .h
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then use the same method and change the index number to suit where you wish to go. This works for me. But it is fairly limited. As I mentioned in the comments, if you already have the swipe action, this isn't overly necessary.

I am not sure what you mean in your question about needing to change the VC as well, but to change the view controller you can use this code:

```
-(IBAction)changeVCs:(UIButton *) sender{

    //The name of your storyboard is normally "Main"
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];

    YourTargetViewContollerName * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theIdentifierNameOfYourStoryBoardVC"];
    //you can give your view controller an identifier using the identity
    //inspector in the right window of xcode 

    //This code then push it to the new view
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: vc animated:YES];
    //alternatively you can use present which is the same as modally
    //[self.navigationController presentViewController: vc animated:YES completion: nil];
}
```

Comment: ill try to make my self more clear: how can i use the upper function (page1) not in the uipageviewcontroller but inside of the vc itself. :)

Comment: Change pages using a button in a view controller? Exactly as I have stated. The button "page1" is on your view controller and controls your embedded page view.

Comment: no sorry, i have three VCs each one have 2 buttons i have another (!) UIpageViewController that is displaying the three VCs. my goal is that the six buttons (two in each VC) could navigate. lets say i have vc1,2,3:vc1 have two buttons that should navigate to vc2,vc3. but how can i use [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil]; to set the view displayed in PageView  from vc1,2,3

Comment: I am not really understanding how the code above isn't doing exactly that. I do not know if you are correctly understanding how the UIPageViewController works or whether you do not know how to implement the code correctly. Have you got the swipe action working correctly in your setup?

Comment: i found a solution thanks i used: nsnotificationcenter

Comment: So you have alerts popout or? Would love to see the solution man, post it on here and if people find it interesting you will get points :-)